# Apache reverse proxy to websocket in same context as http

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, websocket

I have an Apache/2.4.6 installation working as a reverse proxy for some applications. Now I have to configure another one. HTTP proxying is working great, but in some sections of the webpage, the client tries to start a websocket connection.

The problem is that the url is partially shared:

HTTP request: `http://domain/context/[whatever]`

WS request: `ws://domain/context/specific-text?param1&param2`

Cannot use `If` (checking the protocol) as ProxyPass cannot go inside `<If>`.

Tried setting:

```
<Location /context/specific-text>
    ProxyPass ws://internal.domain/context/specific-text
```

Before

```
<Location /context/>
    ProxyPass http://internal.domain/context/
```

But doesn't work, guess because of the (non existant) trailing slash.

More data:

- The socket is complaining about not liking a "200" code, Apache is not returning a ws conection but, to some point, the proxying is being made.
- Tried with and without `<Location>`
- Thought of rewriting `specific-text` to `specific-text/` but I don't like to manipulate things I don't manage. The application is a paid product, can't ask if it would harm anything. Well, I could, I'd just wouldn't expect any answer.